# Adding Partial View with Switch Case in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, switch-statement

I am working on a Partial view that is controlled by a Switch case statement in my controller function for Login and Register but after logging in successfully, it only refreshes the page and doesnt redirect on the case that is used on the login controller function , My problem is how can I prevent to go in the `return View(model)`

Here is my Main Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Dashboard(RegisterModel model1, LogOnModel model2, string returnUrl, string btnReturn, string Role, FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            switch (btnReturn)
            {
                  case "Register":
                  DashboardRegister(model1, Role, formCollection);
                  break;
                  case "Login":
                  DashboardLogin(model2, returnUrl);
                  break;
                    }

           ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles().ToList());
            DashboardRegisterLogin model = new DashboardRegisterLogin
            {
                RegisterModel = model1,
                LogOnModel = model2
            };

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Controller Function for Register:

```
public ActionResult DashboardRegister(RegisterModel model1, string Role, FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            String name = formCollection["txtClientName"];

                // Attempt to register the user
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                Membership.CreateUser(model1.UserName = model1.Email, model1.Password, model1.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(model1.UserName, Role);
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model1.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model1.UserName, "Employer"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("ClientCustomerDetails", "Customer");
                    }
                    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model1.UserName, "Worker"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("WorkerInfo", "Worker");
                    }
                    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model1.UserName, "Administrator"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("ClientDetails", "Client");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                }


            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model1);
        }
```

Controller Function for Login:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DashboardLogin(LogOnModel model2, string returnUrl)
        {

                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model2.UserName, model2.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model2.UserName, model2.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model2.UserName, "Employer"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("WorkerIndex", "Worker");
                    }
                    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model2.UserName, "Worker"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("PositionIndex", "Position");
                    }
                    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model2.UserName, "Administrator"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("ClientDetails", "Client");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }


            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model2);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return here as you're not using the results of those methods:

```
switch (btnReturn)
{
    case "Register":
        return DashboardRegister(model1, Role, formCollection);
    case "Login":
        return DashboardLogin(model2, returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, just advanced into the new error encountered! :D